# Poisson distribution where x is at least 1

Tags: self-study, distributions, poisson-distribution, conditional-probability, truncation

[image]

Is this as simple as saying that the probability that x equals zero is $e^{-λ}$, so the probability that x is 1,2,..... is $1-e^{-λ}$, so we just divide the usual pmf for poisson distribution by the new subset, or divide the usual poisson distribution pmf by $1-e^{-λ}$, which gives us exactly what we are asked to prove?

or in other words, the $P(X=i|X>0)$ just equals the following:

intersection of the probability that X=i and probability that X>0 OVER the probability that X>0, with intersection of the probability that X=i and probability that X>0 just being the probability that X=i

Comment: You should add the self study tag.  If you understand conditional probability you should know why your explanation is correct.

Comment: I added the self study tag.  I feel like I understand it I was just looking for more of a confirmation that the intersection of the probability that X=i and probability that X>0 is just the probability that X=i.  I also start doubting myself for proofs like these when the answer is so simple. Usually our proofs are much more complicated.

Comment: One way to check your work is to devise an alternative solution.  Such an alternative is available by considering that the expression given for $p_Y(i)$ is tantamount to saying it is *proportional* to $\lambda^i/i!$. Use the Law of Total Probability to find the coefficient of proportionality.  It's not that hard: exploit the facts that the sum of all Poisson probabilities must be $1$ and that the chance that $X=0$ is $e^{-\lambda}$.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the definition of conditional probability which is:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\: \cap \: B)}{P(B)}$

I hope that helps you justify your reasoning.

Comment: Here A={X=i} and B = {X>0}.  Note that for i=0 A and B are disjoint.  So in that case P(A and B)=0.